# How do i get the text value of the text box as its title attribute using Jquery?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

How can I get the input value of a textbox as it's title value by my using jQuery, I have tried this:

```
$('#txtClientName').attr('title', $('#txtClientName').val());
```

and

```
$('#txtClientName').attr('title', $(this).val());
```

but none of them are working.

Comment: Are you sure that `txtClientName` id is unique through out the DOM? please share your html code

Comment: First should work? What is `this` in second version ?

Comment: <div class="col-md-3 required">
                    <label>Client Name</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <input type="text" id="txtClientName" class="form-control" maxlength="100" />
                </div>

Comment: And how are you verifying that the title value is being set? And have you added a event handler?

Comment: And when are you setting the `title`? I mean on which event?

Comment: please share whole keydown code in your post. Use edit link to edit your question.

Comment: try this : `$('input[name=txtClientName]').change(function() {$(this).attr('title', $(this).val());});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, check this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5w1fuha7/11/). i don't know why its not working for you. you must be missing something.

### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="inputBox" />
```

### JQuery

```
$(function(){
  $("#inputBox").on('keydown',function(){
  $(this).attr('title',$(this).val());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have created this using button click event. change this according to your requirement. you can use whatever event you want. Keydown, Key press or Change event.

```
<input type="text" id="txtClientName" />
<input type="button" value="test" id="btnSubmit" />       

 $("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
    $('input').attr('title', $('#txtClientName').val());
   });
```

or elase you can use change event

```
<input type="text" id="txtClientName" />

$("#txtClientName").change(function(){
    $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/bFw2h/62/)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet.

```js
$("input[id=txtClientName]").change(function() {
  $(this).attr('title', $(this).val());

  // for testing just print it in a console or in an alert.
  console.log($(this).attr('title'));
  alert($(this).attr('title'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtClientName" title="This is a title." />
<input type="button" value="Get" id="btnSubmit" />
```

---

**[Working JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jokers/67vc356a/).**